# CreateFile fails to open domain printer (ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)

Tags: winapi, printing, dns, createfile

I ran into an interesting problem. A searched many ways but I coundn't found any solution.

The problem is that I'm trying to open a shared printer in a domain with CreateFile function but it returns ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND errorcode.
If I use prompt and type

```
copy file.txt \\computer\printer
```

than it successfully completes the copy with result

> 1 file copied.

The CreateFile parameters is the following:

```
HANDLE file = CreateFile(printer, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
if (file == ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE)
{
    char buffer[256];
    sprintf_s(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "ErrorCode: %i", GetLastError());
    MessageBox(NULL, buffer, "Error opening the file", MB_ICONERROR); 
}
```

or

```
HANDLE file = CreateFile(printer, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

if (file == ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE)
{
    char buffer[256];
    sprintf_s(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "ErrorCode: %i", GetLastError());
    MessageBox(NULL, buffer, "Error opening the file", MB_ICONERROR); 
}
```

where printer containing the '\\host\printer' string according to the debugger.
I build it with Visual Studio 2005 SP1.

I tried to add the printer as Local priter as found on many places but it just resulted that the CreateFile just returned immediately.

Edit: On Windows XP it work perfectly. Windows 7 is the issue.

Edit2: The FOPEN function solves the problem so very likely the windows 7 implementation of function will be the issue.

Comment: It's hard to interpret ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND any way other than the obvious. There's no object with that name.

Comment: I'm hoping that someone have expereince with this exact same problem. Because it seems like that from the command prompt the same printer in the same name and form is available.

Comment: I'm going to leave at this point. I've spent enough time on the wild goose chase that you first set. I guess somebody else will help.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Hopefully next time I could give a bit more detailed desription about the problem. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: So the solution is that the creationdisposition must be CREATE_NEW instead of OPEN_EXISTING.

I found that the fopen worked so I looked back what is the difference.